# PostgreSQL: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone == timestamp without time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have created below trigger and function for update on function where I want to exclude trigger execution when there are update on two columns 'frm' and 'upto' which are of type  "timestamp without time zone"

In trigger function I am checking for updates on these two columns

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ff() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
    if((old."frm" == New."frm") and (old."upto" == New."upto") ) then
        insert into TG_TABLE_NAME (select * from inserted );
        New."from" := old."from"; 
        NEW."upto" := current_timestamp;
        RETURN NEW; 
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
 END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger update_trig2 after update on dd 
for each row execute procedure ff();`
```

After running update query i am getting below error in postgreSQL

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone == timestamp without time zone

Comment: The comparison operator is `'='` , not `'=='` .

Comment: As I remember: `plsql` language initially designed by Oracle based on `Ada` language which based on `Pascal` language. So as you can see the assignment operator is `:=` and the equality operator is `=` (however the inequality operator could be both `<>` and `!=`)

Comment: Thanks that works now but having below error
ERROR: relation "tg_table_name" does not exist LINE 1: insert into TG_TABLE_NAME (select * from inserted ) 
Could you please tell if TG_TABLE_NAME is not a corrrect way to refer table which is invoking trigger??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison operator is `=` in SQL and PL/pgSQL.

So you need to replace `==` with `=`

Comment: ERROR:  relation "tg_table_name" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into TG_TABLE_NAME (select * from inserted )

Comment: could you please tell if  TG_TABLE_NAME is not a corrrect way to refer table which is invoking trigger in postgresql 9.4.4?

Comment: Please open a different question for this. Also, since it answered your original question please mark it as the correct answer.